# PHP showing menu tree in dropdown list

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Function to menu tree:

```
function category_tree($parent_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE parent_id ='".$parent_id."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo "<div id=\"wrapper\">
    <div id=\"navmenu\">";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)):
        $i = 0;
        if ($i == 0) echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>' . $row->name;
        category_tree($row->id);
        echo '</li>';
        $i++;
        if ($i > 0) echo '</ul>';
    endwhile;
    echo "</div>
    </div>";
}
```

The CSS file:

```
#navmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navmenu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:30px;
}

#navmenu li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background:#09F;

}

#navmenu ul li a{
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#000066;
    padding-top:7px;
}

#navmenu ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top:30px;
}

#navmenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}

#navmenu li:hover {
    background:#3366CC;
}

#navmenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover{
    background:#03C;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Database for recursive menu:

[image]

The result is without using div element (id=wrapper,id=navmenu) is working well, see:

[image]

When i put back div elements (id=wrapper,id=navmenu), its not happen what i want:

[image]

I want: when my cursor on "Felso menu" show the dropdown menu (Sport, Ekszer, Egyeb), and if my cursor on "Foci" show the dropdown menu (Mezek, Egyeb, Utok, Labdak), etc... Any ideas how can I do that, or how to fix my code?

Comment: Could you please share the menu table structure, and explain more about which div you are talking?

Comment: @YazidErman I share the table structure in first post and edited divs. But only 2 div have in this code : echo "<div id=\"wrapper\">
    <div id=\"navmenu\">";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I sloved this problem, here is my code:

```
function get_menu_tree($parent_id)
{
    global $conn;
    $menu = "";
    $sqlquery = " SELECT * FROM menu where parent_id='" .$parent_id . "' ";
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlquery);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $menu .="<li><a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['name']."</a>";

        $menu .= "<ul>".get_menu_tree($row['id'])."</ul>"; //call  recursively

        $menu .= "</li>";

    }
    return $menu;
}
```